# Set a ViewState using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a CustomWebUserControl of a GridView and to move around the items I use a ViewState, now I need to move the SelectedIndex when I click on the row, the process gonna be:

1. Click in the expected row;
2. Set the value of rowIndex in a currentItemTextBox.Text;
3. This value gonna be input on the ViewState using the TextChanged event;
4. I'll Call a DataBind for my GridView to my internal methods select the currentRow using this ViewState.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=mainGridView.ClientID%> tr").click(function () {
            var ind = $(this).index();
            $("#<%=currentIndexTexBox.ClientID%>").val(ind);
        });
    });
</script>
```

*When the script set the value the TextChanged event isn't call.

I hope that you can understand my scenario.enter code here

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add AutoPostBack="True" in you TextBox. This will call the OnTextChanged event.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="currentIndexTexBox" runat="server" OnTextChanged="CurrentIndexTextBoxOnTextChanged()" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```